# 90s (or earlier) short story about an old man turning children into stone on Halloween night

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I'm looking for a short story, (I think geared towards kids, because that's the age range when I first read it, around 1995-1996) of the horror genre, in which a group of kids on Halloween night go to prank this old man's house, only to find that he can actually turn people into stone and that he's done this before - there are statues in his garden/front yard that were actually kids from decades ago that were turned into stone. However, the old man could also (I think) turn them back into flesh and blood, as he did this with the first set of kids after trapping the second group.

The only other thing I can remember about this story is one of the end lines, spoken by the old man: "Midas, they used to call me..."

Comment: *Midas*? Didn't he turn things to gold not stone?